# IntValidator-using qml

Tags: qml

I am new to qml. In my text input box its taking only 9 digits using `intValidator`. How to read more than 10 digits???

can anyone please help me.

code goes here

```
TextInput 
{       
    id: uid  
    maximumLength: 100                      
    width: maximumLength * 20    
    focus: true     
    validator: IntValidator{bottom:0; top:9999999999}   
    KeyNavigation.down: bioSelector    
}
```

Comment: It seems that typically IntValidator supports numbers only upto 2147483647 (mentioned in official documentation). Take a look at this page http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-doublevalidator.html. This can have a higher value than the IntValidator. You need to use this property decimal : 0. So this option may work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do this:**

```
validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /\d+/ }
```

Comment: But this prohibits to add a signed number. I see that seems like the OP doesn't want to add negative numbers, but anyway :)

Comment: If you want to add signs this might help: `^[+,-]?\d+`